# How to sync folder RCLONE?

Tags: synchronization

I want sync folder with rclone.
My command is:

> rclone sync "/var/html/**" "Yandex:Backups/git" -v --dry-run

What I do wrong?
Because I receive message

> Transferred:      0 Bytes (0 Bytes/s)
>   Errors:                 0
>   Checks:                 0
>   Transferred:            0
>   Elapsed time:      1m0.5s

But in folder has many files!

Comment: But if sync one file alll okey!

Answer (score 0):

If you are including the `--dry-run` flag, this will test your rclone command without changing or transferring any files.

From the rclone documentation for [dry run](https://rclone.org/docs/#n-dry-run):

> -n, --dry-run
>
> Do a trial run with no permanent changes. Use this to see what rclone would do without actually doing it. Useful when setting up the sync command which deletes files in the destination.

Try omitting that flag and running the command again, like so:

```
rclone sync -v "/var/html/**" "Yandex:Backups/git"
```